# Time Complexity of T(n) = 2 * sqrt(n) * T(sqrt(n)) + c*lgn

Tags: math, analysis, recurrence

I have been trying to solve this question but I could not find anything.

My approach:

`n=2^k` then `S(k) = k * S(k/2) + c*k`

Now, I dont know what to do next. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: T(n) = 2 * sqrt(n) * T(sqrt(n)) + c*lgn is not an algorithm, so you can not measure its time complexity. Clarify.

Comment: You really have not given ANY info at all.   Which of these variables are constants? Which represent the size or complexity of the problem?  What are you trying to solve for? What technique are you using?

Comment: Your substitution makes no sense to me whatsoever.

Comment: `sqrt(n)` is not equal to `k/2` when `n = 2^k`. For `n = 2^k`, `sqrt(n)` is `sqrt(2)^k`.

Comment: @EricLippert This is actually a fairly standard substitution to make in cases where the problem size decreases geometrically.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves sqrt(2^k) = (2^k)^(1/2) = 2^(k/2). If using the substitution n = 2^k, then the size of the problem of size sqrt(n) has size 2^(k/2), so if you let S(k) = T(2^k), then the recurrence would be correct.

Comment: @abra the op is trying to characterize the time of the algorithm by creating a recurrence and solving it, but the master theorem doesn't apply to this recurrance.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Well it's definitely wrong to "reuse" the function name `T`, because it's a different function. Also the correct recurrence when resolved is `S(k) = 2^(k/2 + 1) * S(k/2) + c*k`, so OP made a mistake somewhere

Comment: @NiklasB. Where did the +1 come from?

Comment: @templatetypedef: `2 * 2^(k/2) = 2^(k/2 + 1)`. OP seems to have simplified this term to `k`, which is plain wrong

Comment: @NiklasB. Gotcha - I thought that the +1 was inside the S, not outside.

Comment: @EricLippert: The substitution OP tried and failed is `S(k) := T(2^k)`. In some cases this helps get a recurrence for `S` that can be  solved with the master theorem

Comment: @templatetypedef ah thanks for explaining that. The op is using k to mean two different things and that was confusing to me.

Comment: @EricLippert: He also uses `T` to mean two different things which is not just confusing but mathematically incorrect ;)

Comment: Try asking this question on the theoretical computer science site, and more carefully explain your work.

Comment: Would likely be more appropriate for [cs.se] or [math.se].

Comment: @libik: That's good, but it doesn't change the fact that the question is off-topic here. In my opininion we should refrain from answering these questions to their full extend to discourage other users from asking questions that are similarly off-topic and badly researched.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to write it down for several recursion cycles, you get this :

```
2*n^(1/2) [2*n^(1/4) (2*n^(1/8) . T(n^(1/16) + c log n) + c log n] + c log n
```

If you try to count it, it would be (assymptoticaly) :

```
2^log n * n^(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/log n) + 2^(log n) * n(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/log n) * c * log n
```

By sumation of series and thanks to that `2^log_2 n = n` you get (assymptoticaly) :

```
n^2 + c * n^2 * log n
```

Which actually is assymptoticaly : `n^2(1 + c * log n) = n^2(c * log n) = n^2 * c * log n`

Result : `T(n) = O(c * n^2 * log n`)

Comment: If you put the cut-off of the recursion at 2, then the number of recursion steps is fixed by n^(1/2^k)=2 or n=2^(2^k) or k=log(log(n)), so that in total only T(n)=O(n*log(n)) remains. The long computation is at the same question at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/695286/115115